# How to Get rid of ClassCastException

Tags: java, classcastexception

Lets assume i have 2 totally different user-defined classes `A` and `B`.

`A a = new A();`

`B b = new B();`

`. . .`

`. . .`

`a = (A) b; //I'm pretty sure this raises a ClassCastException, but how to deal with this issue?`

Comment: What do you mean by 'how to deal with it'. If it's going to raise a `ClassCastException` it is most likely going to do it at compile time. If you want to trap it at runtime use a try-catch block. More clarity in the question is required.

Comment: @BrettWalker `ClassCastExceptions` don't happen at compile time. Compilation errors happen at compile time.

Comment: @OP While we're at it, what do you mean by 'I'm pretty sure?'. Don't you know? If it doesn't, you have no reason to post this question at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, unless B derives from A.
That's the point of a ClassCastException.

But since A and B are totally different, why would you want to convert them in the first place?

Comment: Technically that is an oversimplification.  Full details here: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.5   It is true that you can't cast between "totally unrelated classes" but "unless A derives from B" is not completely accurate.  #justsaying

Comment: You beat me to it - it should be "unless B derives from A". Corrected.

Answer (score 0):

Testing before assign the variable.

In java:

```
if(a instanceof B)
    b = (B) a;
```

In C#:

```
if(a is B)
    b = (B) a;
```

But as someone mentioned if you do not derive the class a and b from c I cant see to much benefit of this assignment.

Comment: In Java, it is not enough to have a common ancestor; one must be ancestor of another. They already have Object as common ancestor.